# Transactions Log fails to shrink / release vfl

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

The past two nights, our nightly index job has caused our log drive to fill up.   We complete log file backups every 15 minutes, and the log file still grew to 250GB.  This is a SQL Server 2008R2 SP3 instance.

Our DBCC LOGINFO shows 1500 rows, with all but 6 with a status of 2.

There are no open transactions.  (dbcc opentran)
The wait_type_desc = 2 / Backup Log
The database used to replicated, (long ago). Even ran the command to turn off replication.

However, completing a log backup does not seem to clear the VLFs.   The only way I've been able to clear is to convert the database to simple recovery and then shrink the logfile.   Which, obviously, this is not desirable.

I'm not sure where else to look.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the nightly index job is going to grow the log to 250GB, what are you going to gain by shrinking it temporarily?

Comment: I wanted to shrink, because it was filling up the log drive.   We have a 400GB drive.   Up until 2 days ago, we were fine with space, as we were only using 150-200GB.   I mis-spoke, it was the rebuild, PLUS the other transactional activity on the database.